# What's the best way to define this native interface for .NET consumption?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a library whose functionality I want to eventually expose to .NET.  The method I want to expose has the following signature:

`void DoSomething(std::list<SomeStruct>& someList);`

The variable `someList` gets populated by `DoSomething`.

I know how to export from the library already.  My main question is what would a ".NET friendly" interface look like for this function?  I'd assume that `std::list` is a bad idea if I want to use C# with P/Invokes.

What other options are there?  As the caller, I won't know the size of the buffer that I should pass in ahead of time.  Also, as the caller, I'd rather not make multiple calls to the function with small fixed-sized buffers nor would I want to pass in a super large buffer.

What's the best practice for this case?

Comment: You cannot expose C++ classes to managed code through pinvoke.  Only C++/CLI would work in a scenario like this.  You are still copying list elements, that's unavoidable unless it is a simple type.  A struct is not simple.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant -- I'm OK with not using the STL list class and working with a (native) dynamically allocated array instead.  How is that approach regarded?  Is it too mistake prone (with respect to freeing memory on the managed side)?   Would such an interface pass the "laugh" factor?

Comment: You are asking an entirely different question from the one you posted here.  Edit or re-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a struct for use in the pinvoke call. Decorate it on native and mnaged sides, so that the packing is the same on each side. As for the variable sized out parameter, you could use ::GlobalAlloc to allocate an array that can then be deallocated in C#. Pass out an item count as well. In C#, the Marshal type has various methods to use to work with a GlobalAlloc'd array.

Comment: I'll flesh this out with some detail when I get to work tomorrow, unless somebody else gives a better answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I can pick up the pieces from there... but I'm wondering how "standard" is this approach?

Comment: Well, sorry for totally forgetting about this, but good to know it was useful to some extent. As to "standardicity", I'm really not sure!